# What does a rails console prompt ending with a single quote mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run the

```
2.1.5 :004 > location=Location.find_or_create_by(name: 'Dave & Buster's Hilliard')
```

my rails console doesn't return anything and the prompt changes to

```
2.1.5 :005'>
```

(note the single quote).

Why am I not getting any return from the find_or_create_by method?

Why is the prompt changing and what does it mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you've accidentally broken out of your string and is waiting for you to end the current string.

Change this:

```
'Dave & Buster's Hilliard'
```

(Note the 3x single quotes) to this:

```
"Dave & Buster's Hilliard"
```

OR

```
'Dave & Buster\'s Hilliard'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input does not end..

```
2.1.5 :004 > location=Location.find_or_create_by(name: 'Dave & Buster's Hilliard')
```

should be..

```
2.1.5 :004 > location=Location.find_or_create_by(name: "Dave & Buster's Hilliard")
```

and you will not see the

```
2.1.5 :005'>
```

at the end.. you simple have a typo in your input, because you have one ' to many.. :-)..